# "Sorry the results for this poll are no longer available."

Tags: linkedin

I [posted a poll](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-comfortable-is-NeuroSky-MindWave-3572341.S.130985046?qid=35b46052-df06-44cb-b98b-9e4ec9cf70e5&goback=.gmp_3572341) one year and a half ago in a LinkedIn group. It now says:

> Sorry the results for this poll are no longer available.

Does that mean the moderators removed the results for the poll?

Or do LinkedIn hide the results of a poll after some time?

Any other potential explanation?

[image: screenshot]